# $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$, show that $(X \times Y) \setminus (A \times B) = (X \setminus A) \times (Y \setminus B)$ is not always true.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I want to prove that $(X \times Y) \setminus (A \times B) = (X \setminus A) \times (Y \setminus B)$ with $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ is not always true. However, I have difficulties to understand how this can be shown.

The solution of the right side of the equation is a group of Cartesian products of the form: $\{(x,y) | (x \in X \wedge y \in Y) \wedge (x \notin A \wedge y \notin Y)\}$, isn't it?

I would write the solution of the left side of the equation the same way, so I do not know how they are different and so I can not find an example that shows that the equation does not always have to be true. Can somebody explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point is in the left hand side if it is in $X \times Y$, so of the form $(x,y)$ with $x \in X, y \in Y$, but not in $A \times B$, so it is not of the form $(a,b)$ with $a \in A, b \in B$. But this can happen in two diferent ways: $x \notin A$ *or* $y \notin B$. In the right hand side **both** are the case, while either one suffices not to be in $A \times B$.

Answer (score 1):

$X=Y=\mathbb{R},A=B=[0,1]$,

$(X \times Y) \setminus (A \times B) =\Big((-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\Big)\cup \Big(\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)\Big)$

$(X \setminus A) \times (Y \setminus B)=(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)\times (-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)$

In particular, $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is in the first not the second.

The correct case is that you delete a rectangle, but the incorrect one you delete a cross.

Answer (score 1):

The set :

> $(X \times Y) \backslash (A \times B)$

is obtained from the set $\{ (x,y) | (x∈X ∧ y∈Y) \}$, "deleting" all couples from the set $\{ (x,y) | (x∈A ∧ y∈B) \}$.

Thus, a couple $(x,b)$, with $x \in X$ and $b \in B$ will be in it, while the same couple will not belong to $(X \backslash A) \times (Y \backslash B)$.

---

Let :

> $A = \{ 1, 2 \} \subseteq X = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$

and :

> $B = \{ v, w \} \subseteq Y = \{ v, w, z \}$.

$\langle 3, c \rangle$ is the unique element in $(X \backslash A) \times (Y \backslash B)$, while $\langle 3, a \rangle , \langle 3, b \rangle , \langle 3, b \rangle \in (X \times Y) \backslash (A \times B)$.